# multiple figures generated by python loop but drawn only after loop ends

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, plot, iteration

I have the following code which take a list of object, and for each object draws a figure from data stored in the object:

```
def Plot(self, *figures , wait = True):


    def plot(fig,n):
        fig.fig = plt.figure(n)
        print("Ploting figure {} for file {}\n".format(n,fig.name))
        fig.Plot()
        plt.show()
        if wait:
            input("Press Enter to continue to next figure")

    if not figures:
        figures = self.figures            
        for n,fig in figures.items():
            plot(fig,n)
    else:
        for n,fig in enumerate(figures):
            plot(fig,n)
```

fig.Plot() is the function which handles the plotting. When running 'Plot', a figure is generated at each iteration of the loop, but the actual drawing happens only after the loop finishes.

What I am trying to achieve is that at each iteration the figure is generated and the plot is drawn before continuing to the next iteration.

Comment: After some more googling i found a solution at :

http://physicalmodelingwithpython.blogspot.co.il/2015/07/displaying-plots-inside-loops.html

where the line: 
    "if wait:
            input("Press Enter to continue to next figure")"

should be replaced with:
    "while True:
        if plt.waitforbuttonpress(): break"

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

After some more googling i found a solution at : physicalmodelingwithpython.blogspot.co.il/2015/07/… where the line: "if wait: input("Press Enter to continue to next figure")" should be replaced with: "while True: if plt.waitforbuttonpress(): break"

plt.waitforbuttonpress() returns True is a key is presses and False if the mouse button is pressed allowing to stop the loop in the function and return to the console.

I added the keyword 'Startat' to be able to resume later from the next figure in the list (something which can also be accomplished with a suitable decorator).

A more elegant solution could probably be implemented using python event handling routines, of which i know as much as John Snow.

The full Function (some keywords are irrelevant for the original question):

```
def Plot(self, figures=None, wait=True, Save=False, Legendtitle=False, Startat=0):

    def plot(fig, n):

        print("Ploting figure {} for file {}\n".format(n, fig.name))
        fig.Plot(Legendtitle)
        if Save:
            fig.SavePlot()   
        if wait:    
            while True:
                if plt.waitforbuttonpress():
                    break
                else:
                    return True


    if not figures:
        figures = self.figures
        for n, fig in figures.items(): 
            if n>= Startat:                   
                if plot(fig, n):
                    break


    else:
        for n, fig in enumerate(figures):
            if n>= Startat:
                if plot(fig, n):
                    break
```